# Sort comments by votes?

Tags: php, sql

I'm making an application that is similar to stackoverflow in that it has ratings for questions and answers and I also have tabs that show comments by oldest, newest and votes. I'm having trouble sorting by votes.

Here is my function:

```
 /**
     *
     * @param int $threadid
     * @param string $tab
     * @param object $voting referencing Voting.class.php (may not be needed)
     * @return database query/array 
     */
    public function getComments($threadid, $tab = 'oldest', $voting = null) {
        if ($tab == 'oldest') {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE threadid = :threadid ORDER BY date ASC";
        } else if ($tab == 'newest') {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE threadid = :threadid ORDER BY date DESC";
        } else if ($tab == 'votes') {
            //i dont know what to do here? read below for more explanation
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE threadid = :threadid ORDER BY date ASC";
        }

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':threadid', $threadid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row;
    }
```

Here is my database design:

```
**comments:** | id | userid | threadid | message | date |

**commentsrating:** | userid | commentid | voteup | votedown |
```

If ratings are in a separate table from comments is it possible to make a query for `$tab == 'votes'` that will conform with the rest of the code?

and finally HTML:

```
<?php //Get comments
if (isset($_GET['tab'])) {
    $getComments = $thread->getComments($threadid, $_GET['tab'], $voting);
} else {
    $getComments = $thread->getComments($threadid);
} ?>

    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($getComments); $i++) { ?>
               <p>
    <?php echo $getComments[$i]['message']; ?>
               </p>
               <p>  
                   <span class="bid_votes_count" id="bid_votes_count<?php echo $getComments[$i]['id'] ?>">
    <?php echo $voting->getEffectiveCommentVotes($getComments[$i]['id']) . " votes"; ?>
                   </span>

                   <span class="bid_vote_buttons" id="bid_vote_buttons<?php echo $getComments[$i]['id'] ?>">
                      <a href="javascript:;" class="bid_vote_up" id="<?php echo $getComments[$i]['id'] ?>"></a>
                      <a href="javascript:;" class="bid_vote_down" id="<?php echo $getComments[$i]['id'] ?>"></a>
                  </span>
              </p>
    <?php } ?>

Thanks in advance!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `rating` field to the `comments` table and maintain it manually or with trigger on `commentsrating` table.

Obviously, put there pre-calculated value of the rating and now you are able to have a simple and terrible fast question to perform.

Comment: alternately recalculate rating every so often so it's stored with the comment ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll have a look into triggers!

Comment: @Jonny: triggers is not a mandatory anyway. You could also maintain its manually. Like performing `UPDATE ... SET rating = rating + 1 WHERE ...` right after upvote, and -1 after downvote. But the triggers will allow you to don't care of this routine.

Comment: @zerkms: Ok that makes more sense since i havent studied triggers yet, i was going to do that first but its hard for me to grasp the mentality of having another field in comments when i have been always taught not to duplicate code ya'know?

Comment: @zerkms: and what you're saying to do is that what people mean when they say a field has been "denormalized" to say a profile or thread page?

Comment: @Jonny: yes, i forgot to mention this term, correct - it is a denormalization.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way would be storing a running tally of the votes as a field on the comments table (as mentioned in another answer). However you should also consider modifying the **commentsrating** table to make a little more sense and also help with the problem of tallying.

**commentsrating:** | userid | commentid | vote |

The reason you should only have **vote** is because a comment rating can only have a single vote. It can't be both an up AND down vote.

**vote** should be an int(1) +/-. eg. Can be 1 or -1 (or 0 theoretically). This way you can do the following SQL:

```
SELECT c.id, c.message, c.date, SUM(cr.vote) AS 'votes'
FROM `comments` c
JOIN `commentsrating` cr ON c.id=cr.commentid
WHERE c.threadid=':threadid'
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY `votes`
```

The query will take longer than an `order by` total_votes field but this should be done anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason i have voteup and votedown fields is so i could tally how many voted up and down out of curiosity. Would it then be better to add a |votetype| field too if im just going to use |vote|?

Comment: You can consider "1" to be an up vote and "-1" to be a down vote. You could still tally the up votes and down votes respectively by grouping by the "vote" field and doing a COUNT. I can amened my answer to reflect this if you'd like? eg. add more SQL?

Comment: @Joshn Stuart my bad just noticed you already said that. No it's ok i say i can do it i just never thought of it the way you said. Thanks!

Comment: No probs. I'll just clarify why I used an "int" rather than a normalized table (votetype) or an "enum" ("up vote","down vote"). An int(1) uses very little space. You can use SUM to tally the votes for each comment, user or thread. You can use COUNT or ABS(SUM()) to tally all up or down votes. This is all done very quickly. Again if this is going to be in the 100,000s of rows I'd use, as suggested, a tallied field in the comments table to make it super fast.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments c JOIN (SELECT commentid, ". 
       "(SUM(voteup) - SUM(votedown)) votes, " . 
       "FROM commentsrating GROUP BY commentid) i ON " .
       "c.id = i.commentid WHERE c.threadid = :threadid " . 
       "ORDER BY i.votes DESC";
```

Obviously not the best performance with the crazy JOIN, but should get you to "it works," after which you can worry about performance.

Comment: false. there are N rows in `commentsrating` for the each vote.

Comment: the obvious solution - is to use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`, but anyway, it is just a CPU wasting. We could just store calculated value as I proposed in my answer to prevent of unnecessary calculations.

Comment: @zerkms: I agree. I'll just leave this answer here for the heck of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `threadid`=:threadid ORDER BY (SELECT `voteup`-`votedown` FROM `commentsrating` WHERE `commentid`=`comments`.`id`) DESC
```

Try that?

Comment: I would like to give a name to your query: "Hello, fullscan". Dynamic evaluation of vote value added to the correlated subquery will kill mysql server on even small amount of data and visitors.

Comment: also, this query will fail, since it is a row per vote, not row per comment.

Comment: Hehe, this is one of the things I learned the hard way. But with proper indexing it can be pretty fast. Still no replacement for a counter on the comment, though. Perhaps I shouldn't answer questions when tired.